# Programmatically restart Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot and I've got a use case where user can upload a file which should cause a restart of application (since user's upload is used during creation of multiple beans). I know I can avoid restarting the application, but at the moment - this is what I want.

I've found [RestartEndpoint](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/context/restart/RestartEndpoint.java) in Spring-Cloud project, but it doesn't seem like  `ApplicationPreparedEvent` is fired. Is there any other way I can programmatically restart Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this by calling the [`refresh()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#refresh--) method on the Spring ApplicationContext. This will kill and reload all of your beans, so you should be certain that this occurs only when it is safe for your application to do so.

Comment: I have tried it and it does not seem to work, I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts: just call 'refresh' once. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720330/reload-or-refresh-a-spring-application-context-inside-a-test-method

Comment: refresh doesn't work for certain application context in springboot. Will give illegal state exception

Answer (score 3):

I have a special case in which my Spring Boot application, which runs on `Linux`, is required to run as `root`.

Since I run the application as `systemd` service, I can restart it like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/systemctl", "restart", "foo" });
```

If your application is (hopefully) not required to run as `root`, a `setuid` wrapper-script could be used, or better, use `sudo`.

Check this answer on how to do  that:

https://superuser.com/questions/440363/can-i-make-a-script-always-execute-as-root

Answer (score 1):

In your case it might be possible to use the /refresh endpoint (see http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_endpoints) and annotate the beans that depend on the changed configuration with @RefreshScope.

Comment: well, I'm not using Spring Cloud. :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code to restart my application from the code itself. Closing context using a separate thread will not shut the JVM.

```
public class DemoApplication {

private static String[] args;
private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DemoApplication.args = args;
    context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}

public static void restart() {
  
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        context.close();            
        context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, DemoApplication.args);
    });
    thread.setDaemon(false);
    thread.start();
}
```