# Force enable spring-boot DevTools when running Jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am running my spring-boot app in a Docker container, trying to use [remote LiveReload](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart).

The [spring-boot DevTools documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) states that

> Developer tools are automatically disabled when running a fully packaged application. If your application is launched using java -jar or if it’s started using a special classloader, then it is considered a “production application”.

Is there any way to force the enabling of DevTools?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is sketchy, so you decide if it's good for you. **The final solution is the last part of this post**

It's hard to just throw the solution, I first need to explain how I got there. First, why livereload is not enabled when launching outside the IDE:

---

**Understand what is going on**

(1) LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration configuration is conditional on `@ConditionalOnInitializedRestarter/OnInitializedRestarterCondition`:

```
    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnInitializedRestarter
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(DevToolsProperties.class)
    public class LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration {
    ...
```

(2) OnInitializedRestarterCondition retrieves a Restarter instance and checks if it's null otherwise `restarter.getInitialUrls()` returns null. In my case, `restarter.getInitialUrls()` was returning null.

```
class OnInitializedRestarterCondition extends SpringBootCondition {
    @Override
    public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(ConditionContext context,
            AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        Restarter restarter = getRestarter();
        if (restarter == null) {
            return ConditionOutcome.noMatch("Restarter unavailable");
        }
        if (restarter.getInitialUrls() == null) {
            return ConditionOutcome.noMatch("Restarter initialized without URLs");
        }
        return ConditionOutcome.match("Restarter available and initialized");
    }
```

(3) `initialUrls` is initialized in `Restarter.class` through `DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(..)`

```
class Restarter{
    this.initialUrls = initializer.getInitialUrls(thread);
}

class DefaultRestartInitializer{
    @Override
    public URL[] getInitialUrls(Thread thread) {
        if (!isMain(thread)) {
            return null;
        }
        for (StackTraceElement element : thread.getStackTrace()) {
            if (isSkippedStackElement(element)) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return getUrls(thread);
    }

    protected boolean isMain(Thread thread) {
    return thread.getName().equals("main") && thread.getContextClassLoader()
            .getClass().getName().contains("AppClassLoader");
    }
}
```

> > thread.getContextClassLoader()
> >                 .getClass().getName().contains("AppClassLoader")

is only true when running from Eclipse (possibly any IDE? + springboot-maven-plugin?). To Recap:

- isMain() returns false;
- the initialUrls is not initialized;
- the conditional LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration is not configured;
- no livereload.

---

**A SOLUTION:**

Make sure the classloader name is "AppClassLoader" by Creating your own AppClassLoader classloader.
At the very first line of your spring-boot main, replace the classloader with yours:

```
URLClassLoader originalClassLoader = (URLClassLoader)Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(new CustomAppClassLoader(originalClassLoader));
```

Our custom classloader implementation simply delegates to the original one:

```
public class CustomAppClassLoader extends URLClassLoader{

private URLClassLoader contextClassLoader;

public CustomAppClassLoader(URLClassLoader contextClassLoader) {
    super(contextClassLoader.getURLs(), contextClassLoader.getParent());
    this.contextClassLoader = contextClassLoader;
}

public int hashCode() {
    return contextClassLoader.hashCode();
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return contextClassLoader.equals(obj);
}

public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
    return contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(name);
}

public String toString() {
    return contextClassLoader.toString();
}

public void close() throws IOException {
    contextClassLoader.close();
}

public URL[] getURLs() {
    return contextClassLoader.getURLs();
}

public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return contextClassLoader.loadClass(name);
}

public URL findResource(String name) {
    return contextClassLoader.findResource(name);
}

public Enumeration<URL> findResources(String name) throws IOException {
    return contextClassLoader.findResources(name);
}

public URL getResource(String name) {
    return contextClassLoader.getResource(name);
}

public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) throws IOException {
    return contextClassLoader.getResources(name);
}

public void setDefaultAssertionStatus(boolean enabled) {
    contextClassLoader.setDefaultAssertionStatus(enabled);
}

public void setPackageAssertionStatus(String packageName, boolean enabled) {
    contextClassLoader.setPackageAssertionStatus(packageName, enabled);
}

public void setClassAssertionStatus(String className, boolean enabled) {
    contextClassLoader.setClassAssertionStatus(className, enabled);
}

public void clearAssertionStatus() {
    contextClassLoader.clearAssertionStatus();
}
```

}

I configured CustomAppClassLoader as much as I could (calling super with 'url' and 'parent' from the original classloader), but anyway I still delegate all public methods to the original classloader.

It works for me. Now, the better question is do I really want this :)

**A better option**

I think `Spring Cloud's RestartEndpoint` is a better option: [Programmatically restart Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117308/programmatically-restart-spring-boot-application)
However, `RestartEndPoint` does not handle the detection of changes in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that devtools is included in the repackaged archive, like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludeDevtools>false</excludeDevtools>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```