# Does Spring Boot support Hot Deployments in Production environments?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, osgi, hotdeploy

Can we do Hot deployments (updating running code) in Spring Boot applications running outside the IDE.

I see that "spring-boot-devtools" is mainly used when developers work through code changes in their IDE but, am looking for hot deployments in Stage or Production environments.

This 'Hot Deployment' feature was shown as one of the highlight in OSGi when compared with Spring Boot based Microservices. Hence am trying to clarify if such a facility is offered by Spring Boot.

Comment: Speaking as an OSGi advocate: you can always embed OSGi in your application since it is lightweight and designed specifically for embedding. Probably Spring aficionados would frown on this solution though.

Comment: Not hot deployment, but Spring Cloud's RestartEndPoint offers a mean to restart the application:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386168/programatically-restart-spring-boot-application-refresh-spring-context/39389169#39389169

Comment: And this on how to use devtools with a jar (outside of the IDE): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591423/force-enable-spring-boot-devtools-when-running-jar/38113497#38113497

Comment: Could you share any info about your architecture? Is it just one stand-alone spring boot application? In my projects, I use blue-green deployments in a cloud environment which means I deploy the new version of my app and the dns is updated once deployment is successful.