# Programmatically restart Spring Boot application / Refresh Spring Context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, kotlin

I am trying to programmatically restart my Spring Application without having the user to intervene.

Basically, I have a page which allows to switch the mode of the application (actually meaning switching the currently active profile) and as far as I understand I must restart the context.

Currently my code is very simple, it's just for the restarting bit (this is Kotlin by the way):

```
    context.close()
    application.setEnvironment(context.environment)
    ClassUtils.overrideThreadContextClassLoader(application.javaClass.classLoader)
    context = application.run(*argsArray)
```

However the moment I do `context.close()` the JVM exists immediately. I have also tried `context.refresh()` but that seems to simply kill Tomcat/Jetty (tried both just in case it was a Tomcat problem) and then nothing happens.

I have also seen [Programmatically restart Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117308/programmatically-restart-spring-boot-application) but nothing seems to work for me from those answers. Furthermore, I looked into Spring Actuator which supposedly has the `/restart` endpoint, but that doesn't seem to be there anymore?

Comment: I just read something about spring-cloud last time and there was a `refresh endpoint` which refreshes al the beans in the context. Maybe you find something helpful there. [Refresh Scope](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html)

Comment: Why is this tagged "java" ?

Comment: Because I didn't care if somebody had a solution in Java or Kotlin. Kotlin has no significance in this question.

Comment: Then java is not significant either... If you tag Java it would be nice to provide a Java version of the solution at least. (I can do the translation, but probably not all people who program in Java and land here will be able to)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even though Alex's solution *works*, I don't believe in including 2 additional dependencies (`Actuator` and `Cloud Context`) just to be able to do one operation. Instead, I have combined his answer and modified my code in order to do what I wanted.

So, first of all, it is **crucial** that the code is executed using `new Thread()` and `setDaemon(false);`. I have the following endpoint method that handles the restart:

```
val restartThread = Thread {
    logger.info("Restarting...")
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    SpringMain.restartToMode(AppMode.valueOf(change.newMode.toUpperCase()))
    logger.info("Restarting... Done.")
}
restartThread.isDaemon = false
restartThread.start()
```

The `Thread.sleep(1000)` is not required, but I want my controller to output the view before actually restarting the application.

`SpringMain.restartToMode` has the following:

```
@Synchronized fun restartToMode(mode: AppMode) {
    requireNotNull(context)
    requireNotNull(application)

    // internal logic to potentially produce a new arguments array

    // close previous context
    context.close()

    // and build new one using the new mode
    val builder = SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringMain::class.java)
    application = builder.application()
    context = builder.build().run(*argsArray)
}
```

Where `context` and `application` come from the `main` method upon starting the application:

```
val args = ArrayList<String>()
lateinit var context: ConfigurableApplicationContext
lateinit var application: SpringApplication

@Throws(Exception::class)
@JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    this.args += args

    val builder = SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringMain::class.java)
    application = builder.application()
    context = builder.build().run(*args)
}
```

I am not entirely sure if this produces any problems. If there will be, I will update this answer. Hopefully this will be of any help to others.

Comment: As commented above, apparently this works only once, have you observed the same behaviour?

Answer (score 10):

In case it might help someone, here's a pura Java translation of Crembo's accepted answer.

Controller method:

```
@GetMapping("/restart")
void restart() {
    Thread restartThread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Main.restart();
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    });
    restartThread.setDaemon(false);
    restartThread.start();
}
```

Main class (significant bits only):

```
private static String[] args;
private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main.args = args;
    Main.context = SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
}

public static void restart() {
    // close previous context
    context.close();

    // and build new one
    Main.context = SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);

}
```

Comment: OK apparently this approach works only works once... The second time i get a NPE on the context.close(). How can it be null since it is a static member of Main ?? I'm puzzled here.

Comment: It works perfectly for me, also multiple times. Is the sleep really necessary?

Comment: Quoted from the accepted answer: "The Thread.sleep(1000) is not required, but I want my controller to output the view before actually restarting the application."

Answer (score 7):

As was commented already, the restart-via-thread implementations given before only work once, and second time around throw a NPE because context is null.

This NPE can be avoided by having the restart thread use the same class loader as the initial main-invoking thread:

```
private static volatile ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
private static ClassLoader mainThreadClassLoader;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    mainThreadClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

public static void restart() {
    ApplicationArguments args = context.getBean(ApplicationArguments.class);

    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        context.close();
        context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args.getSourceArgs());
    });

    thread.setContextClassLoader(mainThreadClassLoader);
    thread.setDaemon(false);
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: The best answer, it works perfectly

Answer (score 6):

I've solved this issue by using Restarter from Spring Devtools.
Add this to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then use org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter
to call this:

```
Restarter.getInstance().restart();
```

It works for me. Hope this help.

Comment: Using something out of the box is better than, reinventing the wheel.

Comment: When I add Dev Tools to my project and run it in IntelliJ, it is unable to cast the classes in debugging. It works fine when I run the jar directly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `RestartEndPoint` (in `spring-cloud-context` dependency) to restart the Spring Boot application programmatically:

```
@Autowired
private RestartEndpoint restartEndpoint;

...

Thread restartThread = new Thread(() -> restartEndpoint.restart());
restartThread.setDaemon(false);
restartThread.start();
```

It works, even though it will throw an exception to inform you that this may lead to memory leaks:

> The web application [xyx] appears to have started a thread named
>   [Thread-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a
>   memory leak. Stack trace of thread:

**The same answer was provided for this other question (worded differently)**: [Call Spring actuator /restart endpoint from Spring boot using a java function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850762/call-spring-actuator-restart-endpoint-from-spring-boot-using-a-java-function/38851994#38851994)

Comment: Even though your answer wasn't exactly what I needed, I used your answer to find a solution that works for me. See my self-posted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below restart method will work.

`@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

```
private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

public static void restart() {
    ApplicationArguments args = context.getBean(ApplicationArguments.class);

    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        context.close();
        context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args.getSourceArgs());
    });

    thread.setDaemon(false);
    thread.start();
}
```

}`

Comment: why are you closing the context from within the new thread? also, doesnt SpringApplication.run(...) start a thread itself? why explicitly instantiate a new thread for it?