# How do I properly restart a Spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39389169/4037594) to restart my Spring Boot application:

```
Thread restartThread = new Thread(() -> restartEndpoint.restart());
restartThread.setDaemon(false);
restartThread.start();
```

<s>However, the restarted application fails to create beans, ultimately due to a `RejectedExecutionException` thrown when trying to schedule `@Scheduled`-annotated methods:</s>

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myBean' defined in URL [insert-path-here]: Initializetion of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.TaskRejectedException: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@284a4a89[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 21508]] did not accept task: my.package.MyBean.scheduledMethod
```

<s>The logs immediately after the `doRestart()` invocation indicate that the ExecutorService `taskScheduler`is being shut down, which would explain why this is happening. What I'm not entirely sure of is why the ExecutorService isn't recreated.</s> Embarrassingly enough, it turns out that `taskScheduler` was a bean defined by my application and was not annotated `@RefreshScope`. Now the error I'm getting is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'anotherBean' definen in URL[...]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0 ... nested exception is  java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2a95076c has been closed already
```

Scrolling up a bit in the logs reveals that there's an `ApplicationContextException` thrown with the stacktrace containing `doRestart`:

```
org.springframework.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Filters cannot be added to context [/myapp] as the context has been initialized
    at org.springframework.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157)
    ...
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.restart.RestartEndpoint(RestartEndpoint.java:160)
    at my.package.MyBean.lambda$doThingAndRestart$2 (MyBean.java: 118)
```

Googling this error seems to result in a [single page](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/12/secure-java-ee-rest-api) that isn't relevant, although I do note that this application is running on tomcat as well.

I suspect that this is related to the application creating a wrong sort of application context, which is a `AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext`, which doesn't extend [AbstractRefreshableAplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.html).

What do I need to do to get rid of this error?

Please bear with me when I only copy single lines from the stack trace.  I'm on a two-computer set-up, so I can't copy-and paste and am no allowed to otherwise move the logs to a computer connected to the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `RestartEndpoint` only works with Spring's internal Tomcat, not an external one. So, another solution is required. The ones I discovered are

- Using Tomcat's [WatchedResource](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Nested_Components) to re-deploy the server when a configuration file is overwritten. This has the downside of needing to maintain the Tomcat configuration when maintaining the `doThingAndRestart` functionality.
- Using Tomcat's [Manager App](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html). I noticed that the `reload` request blocks until the app is done reloading, which overflowed the heap space.
- Using Spring's [RefreshEndpoint](https://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-commons-parent/1.1.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/endpoint/RefreshEndpoint.html). For whatever reason, this didn't refresh the datasources.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions that works for me was hard reset of the app.
This solution will restart my spring-boot app on the same port, and kill all background process that are left.
I had issues where old reports were still present somewhere in the background, and were added to the new one.
Cleaning and rebuild project while springboot app was running in the background did not help, as well deleting all files related to the report.
Hope this helps

```
public ResponseEntity<String> restart() {
    try {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            // Stop the current application context
            context.close();

            // Kill all background processes (if any)

            // Start the application in a new JVM process
            try {
                String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
                String javaBin = javaHome + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java";
                String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
                String className = SpringBootApplication.class.getName();

                ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(javaBin, "-cp", classpath, className);
                Process process = builder.start();

                // Wait for the process to complete
                process.waitFor();
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        thread.setDaemon(false);
        thread.start();
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Server restarting");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .body("Error restarting server: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```