# Spring: How to hot reload resources under ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I found ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource in [spring framework reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-messagesource)

> As an alternative to ResourceBundleMessageSource, Spring provides a
>   ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource class.  This variant supports
>   the same bundle file format but is more flexible than the standard JDK
>   based ResourceBundleMessageSource implementation.  In particular, it
>   allows for reading files from any Spring resource location (not just
>   from the classpath) and  supports hot reloading of bundle property
>   files (while efficiently caching them in between).  Check out the
>   ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource javadocs for details.

If I understand it correctly, you can change codes in properties files and server will load them instantly at runtime.

How can one achieve hot reload in spring boot based web application?

What is the trigger of hot reload?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reload happens automatically as soon as it detects a new change in the properties file, without needing an additional manual trigger from yourself.

From [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html):

> capable of reloading files based on timestamp changes

For more details, I think it happens at this method [refreshProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html#refreshProperties(java.lang.String,org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.PropertiesHolder)). The one is called by [getProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html#getProperties(java.lang.String))

Answer (score -1):

You can create a bean of `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` like this

```
@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasename("classpath:test");  // name of the resource bundle
    source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    source.setCacheSeconds(10);
    return source;
}
```

To use it you can just autowire `MessageSource` in your class and get messages from the bundle.

```
@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;

public void getMessage() {
   Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
   String message = messageSource.getMessage("some.message", null, locale);
}
```

The `MessageSource` is different from `PropertySource`.
Now, if you are talking about reloading properties that are used to configure spring (like in application.properties), then look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39387272/reload-property-value-when-external-property-file-changes-spring-boot%20here)