# Spring @PropertySource refresh

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How I refresh the @PropertySouce(propertyFile) in spring.

for example :-
There is a parameter in property file :-

```
   MY_APP_NAME=MY APPLICATION
```

and I am using

```
   @Autowired Enviornment env;
```

to get the property value from property file.

After that I want to change the property from "**MY APPLICATION**" to "**APPLICATION**".

```
    MY_APP_NAME=APPLICATION
```

It will need to restart the application but I don't want to restart the application.I want when I change the property it will reflect in application after some seconds.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39387272/reload-property-value-when-external-property-file-changes-spring-boot

Comment: I have a spring-core project now what i do?

Answer (score 0):

if your project is springboot you can use actuator ,  u can use 'http://localhost:port/refresh' to refresh your properties

Comment: I have a spring-core project now what i do?