# Testing Spring's refreshscope properties

Tags: java, spring

We have found that just because we are putting properties into spring's refreshscope, does not mean that we are accessing them in a way that honors the refresh. For example, we might inject a property into a constructor, and even though the property is refreshed, the bean is not refreshed, so the old property lingers. We'd like to test through our main cases to ensure we are actually honoring these refreshes.

What I would like is a test that starts out with property=A, change it in the middle of the test to property=B, and assert that everything is properly updated (so if it was a URL, that we are now calling the new URL).

I keep running into an issue I believe is described here - [Reload or refresh a Spring application context inside a test method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720330/reload-or-refresh-a-spring-application-context-inside-a-test-method)

Forcing a refresh of properties is not supported through code. Am I thinking about this the wrong way or is this really not supported? They claim that testing in this way is probably wrong, but I'm specifically trying to test the refreshability aspect of the code.

Some code to describe what I'm trying to do -

```
@Autowired
Properties properties;

    @Test
public void testRefreshProperties() {
    TestConfigurer.environment.setProperty("downstream.server.baseUrl", "http://modified.com");
    TestConfigurer.context.refresh();
    Assert.assertEquals(
        properties.getBaseUrl(),
        "http://modified.com");
}
```

where TestConfigurer is an initializer that exposes its context and environment, and the Properties class has a baseUrl method that is gathered from the "downstream.server.baseUrl" property.

Comment: Among all the mumbling, it's not clear to me if you've an actual question. If your problem is that your consumers of the properties don't pick up when the properties are updated, that's true.

Comment: My problem is there seems to be no way of unit testing refreshable properties. I can go and make updates to the properties while the app is running and prove that they are picked up, but I would like to mimic this behavior with spring testing tools, and I'm unsure if those tools exist.

Comment: Unit test, no, integration test, yes, and the latter isn't that difficult if you design well. Considering a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean that `SomeOtherBean` uses, it's straightforward to update the former and verify that the latter sees the change.

Comment: a `refresh` of the application context is not the same as refreshing properties. Those are different things and basically what you are testing is not testing the issue you have.