# What is hot refresh?

Tags: java, spring

Here is a snippet from Spring Framework Core from *1.6.1: Lifecycle Callbacks*:

> Also, please note that stop notifications are not guaranteed to come before destruction. On regular shutdown, all `Lifecycle` beans first receive a stop notification before the general destruction callbacks are being propagated. However, on **hot refresh** during a context’s lifetime or on aborted refresh attempts, only destroy methods are called.

What is hot refresh? Does it have something to do with live reloading?

Comment: I assume that this is a minor inconsistency in wording and that they meant to write [hot swapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html)

Comment: @Turing85 Even I thought so, but the same word is repeated twice in Spring Framework Core, you can search for it in *1.15.2. Standard and Custom Events*

Comment: I know, I checked the doc =). Still, I woudl assume it is a minor inconsistency.

Comment: hot refresh is about reloading your `ApplicationContext` without restart the process see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720330/reload-or-refresh-a-spring-application-context-inside-a-test-method

Comment: @josejuan Isn't that *hot swapping*?

Comment: hot swapping imply change the deployment (the binaries) refresh only the context (aka configuration)

Comment: @josejuan It looks like you answered the question. Why don't you turn your comment into an answer so you can get credit?

Comment: @josejuan Correct, but partially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering question by myself.

> [`ContextRefreshedEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch03s13.html) is published when the `ApplicationContext` is initialized or refreshed (for example, by using the `refresh()` method on the `ConfigurableApplicationContext` interface). Here, “initialized” means that all beans are loaded, post-processor beans are detected and activated, singletons are pre-instantiated, and the `ApplicationContext` object is ready for use. As long as the context has not been closed, a refresh can be triggered multiple times, provided that the chosen `ApplicationContext` actually supports such “hot” refreshes. For example, `XmlWebApplicationContext` supports hot refreshes, but `GenericApplicationContext` does not.

[`AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.html):

> Provides a "configLocations" property, to be populated through the `ConfigurableWebApplicationContext` interface on web application startup.

It is the web application context whose config locations property is being replaced without restarting the app.

Comment: I guess I was wrong, sorry. Why would they call it "hot" refreshing?

Comment: Because `"configLocations"` are being replaced I guess.